# Parsing through JSON to display error message

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I want to add a toast message and to return the user to the main activity when my WEBSERVICE returns no data and allow me to explain more.  When a user searches for a query, the webservice returns data to my JSON string that looks like this.

```
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): "all" :    {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "count" : 25,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "questions" : [     {   
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Id" : "20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Subject" : "What is the oldest a bitch can more or less safely breed?",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Content" : "Don't worry I'm not going to breed - both my bitches are getting neutered in the next year, as is my dog! Just that me and a friend were talking about it after talking to the man who gave me Misty (my border collie) who said she could still breed at 7 - I thought the oldest was 5?\n",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Date" : "2010-07-28 18:20:33",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Timestamp" : "1280341233",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Link" : "http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Type" : "Answered",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryId" : 396546021,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryName" : "Dogs",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserId" : "cP16Ctgxaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserNick" : "Kiko",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserPhotoURL" : "http://l.yimg.com/dg/users/1t1USxJpxAAEBQOGZjBMW0-5Wp_EG.medium.jpg",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumAnswers" : 8,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumComments" : 0,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswer" : "You just \"imagined\" that ,dear...not \"thought\". & your imagination is WRONG.\r\n\r\n9 or even 10,for a healthy TOP-PRODUCING bitc-h.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n*&* bitches are SPAYED & dogs are CASTRATED......big scary correct ADULT words.",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererId" : "clN6YITvaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererNick" : "Debunker",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerTimestamp" : "1280317077",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerAwardTimestamp" : "1280835336"
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):        },      {
```

And here is my code of how I parse through this data to get the particular data that I want

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    try {
        Intent in = getIntent();
        String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
        String URL = "http://example.com";
        JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
        try {

            JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

            for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


            String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
            String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
            String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return TAG_QUESTION ;           

}
```

But when the user searches for a query and the webservice returns no results and by no results I mean the webservice data has `"count" : 0,` and it looks like this in my JSON string that looks like this.

```
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): {
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): "all" : {
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "count" : 0,
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "questions" : [     ]
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     }
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): }
```

When this happens I want an toast message to pop up and to return the user to the main activity but I just do not know how to parse through that data when it returns count 0. I already that I need to add a `if` statement in this location

```
        try {
            // if statement here
            JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

            for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


            String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
            String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
            String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);
```

I need to know how to parse `"count" : 0,` so I can display the toast message and then return the user back to the main activity.  Hope you see my idea here and let me know if you are having any trouble try to comprehend what I mean. 
P.S. if you wondering what `JSONParsser` is, it is just the class I use to connect to the webservice and `searchTerm` is me just passing `editText` and encoding it.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) { 

    if(file_URL.equals("0")) { 
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();    

}else{

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                R.layout.listelements,
                new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                R.id.Subject,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Update**

```
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {  

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

                    json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return json;           

            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { 

            int count = 0;
            try {
                count = json.getJSONObject("all").getInt("count");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(count>0) { 
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();    

        }else{

                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                    questionList.add(map);

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                                R.layout.listelements,
                                new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                                R.id.Subject,});

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `count` value, just do

```
int count = json.getJSONObject("all").getInt("count");
```

(you should replace `"count"` by a final variable as you did with the other `JSONObject` in your code)

Then add a `if` before you do

```
JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");
```

But you won't be able to display your toast in the `doInBackground` method, you will have to return the result (a String) and display it in `onPostExecute()` . So far you don't return the right value, you return `TAG_QUESTION`, which must be a final String, meaning that the result of your processing is never used outside of the method.

**UPDATE**

I think you should do like that:

First, you should not do all your processing in `doInBackground()`. In this method you should just retrieve your json, return it and process it in `onPostExecute()`. For that, you will need to change your `AsyncTask` so it looks like this (notice the change in the last parameter, from `String` to `JSONObject`):

```
private class yourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
```

This will tell your program that the return value of `doInBackground()` will be of `JSONObject` type. So what you have to do next is to change your `doInBackground()` so it looks like that (notice again the change in the return value, from `String` to `JSONObject` :

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Intent in = getIntent();
        String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
        String URL = "http://example.com";
        JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

        try {
            json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;           

}
```

Then change the type of the parameter in `onPostExecute()` to `JSONObject`, and do your processing after checking the `count` value:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { 

    int count = json.getJSONObject("all").getInt("count");
    if(count>0) {   // There are some questions to retrieve

        /*  In this part I just copied what you put in your question, 
            I don't know what your goal is so I can't help much, 
            but you have the logic to do so */

        JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


        String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
        String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
        String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
            R.layout.listelements,
            new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
            R.id.Subject,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();    

    }

}
```

Comment: So @Inman Douche, did that finally help you solve your problem?

Comment: which value do I return? `count`?

Comment: In fact in `doInBackground()` you should change `return TAG_QUESTION ;` by 2 return statements : if `count > 0`, you can return the `String ` result of your process; but if `count == 0`, you can return an empty `String`. Then in `onPostExecute()`, you can test if the `String` is empty. If that is the case, you can display your `Toast` message.

Comment: ok, Do you know how I can write this or is there a tutorial where I can see how to write a 2 return statement? and I also posted my `onPostExecute`

Comment: I'll try to update my code with that, but I can't do it just now. I'll try do it by tomorrow!

Comment: Ok, that is perfectly fine

Comment: @inman-douche, I have updated my answer, let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Will this speed up the execution of the `doInBackGround` method?

Comment: I guess so, because you are doing less stuff, but I can't be sure. But the main goal of that is that you will be able to display error messages to your user, which was your original question.

Comment: In my `doInBackGround` method `return json;` I get an syntax error underneath json that says "json cannot be resolved to a variable" I will post all of my global variable in the question

Comment: I have updated my code, that's probably because I declared twice the json variable

Comment: Ok, that fixed it but I have one more question.  when I put `int count = json.getJSONObject("all").getInt("count");
    if(count>0) {` in `onPostExecute` and I surround it with a try and catch `int count;
   try {
    count = json.getJSONObject("all").getInt("count");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   if(count>0) {` I get an syntax error under `count` that says "The local variable `count` may not have been Initialized" and when I do Initialize it this is what It looks like `int count = 0;` Will this affect anything?

Comment: I think you can initialize it with 0 as you did, because if you encounter a `JSONException`, that probably means that there is a problem with your `JSONObject` and that you won't be able to process it. In that case, the best thing is to consider there are no usable questions at all and to warn the user, because you don't know what kind of behavior you app will have with just a part of your json being correct. And you can do that by having `count` equal to 0! So I think that's a good idea. I hope that helps!

Comment: When the web service doesn't return data it finishes the activity but when the web service does return data it still finishes the activity. is there a way around this and I will post full asynctask in question

Comment: First, your test is wrong, it should be `if (count == 0) {`, because you want to call `finish()` when there are no data returned. The fact that it finishes also when you have data probably means that you have an error in your code. So, first change your `if` statement, then check your logs to see what's wrong.

Comment: No problem :) I hope this will help you write great apps!

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can check whether object is available or not(Assuming that count returns 0 in case of no questions)

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {
    static String str = "{" + 
        "\"all\" : {" + 
        "    \"count\" : 0," + 
        "    \"questions\" : [     ]" + 
        "    }" + 
        "}";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

                  JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                  JsonObject jsonString = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(str);
                  JsonObject allObj = jsonString.getAsJsonObject("all");

                  int quesCount = allObj.get("count").getAsInt();
                  if(quesCount == 0){
                  System.out.println("No Object Available as Object Count is : "+quesCount);
                }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this way**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    try {
        Intent in = getIntent();
        String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
        String URL = "http://example.com";
        JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(data.getJSONObject("all").getString("count"))<=0){ //UPDATE HERE
            return "0";
        }
            JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

            for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


            String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
            String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
            String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return TAG_QUESTION ;           

}


@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result==null || result.equals("0")){
                     Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response... This line `if(result==null || result.equals("0")){` shouldn't I replace `result` with my global variable `final String TAG_COUNT = "count";` since that is what I referring to in the parsing part of the code. In my code I had put `TAG_COUNT` to replace `result`

Comment: Did you see my comment?